# SQL Server PATINDEX to match exact string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, patindex

```
SELECT * FROM SYS.COLUMNS WHERE
NAME NOT IN (SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'XXXX'
AND PATINDEX('%' + COLUMN_NAME + '%', 'ABC;XYZ') <> 0);
```

In Table `XXXX`  there are columns like `XY`,`AB`,`ABC`,`XYZ`. Now I only want to exclude `XYZ` and `ABC` columns and keep the `AB` and `XY` columns using `PATINDEX`. I'm not able to do it because only the first column is getting excluded. And if I remove the beginning `%` from `PATINDEX` then both `XYZ` a `XY` are being removed. How can I solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want **CHARINDEX**, not PATINDEX.

```
   SELECT * FROM SYS.COLUMNS 
    WHERE NAME NOT IN (
      SELECT COLUMN_NAME
      FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
      WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'XXXX'
      AND CHARINDEX(COLUMN_NAME + ';', 'ABC;XYZ;') > 0
    );
```

Comment: What I want to know is that should I put column names using a `;` separator or is there a better way? Also your query selects both `XY` and `XYZ` which is not the desired behavior.

Comment: See updated answer to deal with XY and XYZ selection - added ';' terminator to search strings. It does not matter what the separator is, since you're searching for occurrences of strings.